# Win32 transparent fullscreen only works if window size overflows desktop

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, dwm

I'm trying to make a fullscreen transparent window on the desktop that i can render on with opengl.
I don't want to overflow the screen but so far that seems to be the only way i can. It's a pretty dirty hack imo and would hope someone knows of a professional solution.

Here's the code:

```
// libs needed to compile: opengl32 gdi32 dwmapi

#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

HDC hDC;
HGLRC hRC;
HWND hWnd;

bool running=true;

int w=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),h=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

void CreateContext(){
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd; hDC=GetDC(hWnd);
    SetPixelFormat(hDC,ChoosePixelFormat(hDC,&pfd),&pfd);
    hRC=wglCreateContext(hDC); wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hRC);
}

void EnableTransparency(){DWM_BLURBEHIND b={DWM_BB_ENABLE|DWM_BB_BLURREGION,TRUE,CreateRectRgn(0,0,-1,-1)}; DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd,&b);}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam){
    switch(uMsg){
    case WM_CLOSE: running=false; return 0;
    case WM_KEYDOWN: if(wParam==VK_ESCAPE){running=false;} return 0;
    }return DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}

void CreateWin(){
    WNDCLASS wc={};
    wc.lpfnWndProc=WndProc;
    wc.hInstance=GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName="OpenGL";
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,"Title",WS_POPUP,0,-1,w,h+1,0,0,wc.hInstance,0); // increasing height by 1 pixel
    ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW);
    EnableTransparency();
    CreateContext();
}

void PumpMessages(){MSG msg; while(PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))DispatchMessage(&msg);}

int main(){
    CreateWin();
    glViewport(0,0,w,h); // the visible screen area (excluding h+1 overflow)
    while(running){
        PumpMessages();
        glClearColor(0,0,0,1); glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // fill solid black
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); // transparent triangular window
        glColor4f(1,0,0,0.5f); glVertex3f( 0, 1,0); // red   (center)
        glColor4f(0,1,0,0.5f); glVertex3f(-1,-1,0); // green (left)
        glColor4f(0,0,1,0.5f); glVertex3f( 1,-1,0); // blue  (right)
        glEnd();
        SwapBuffers(hDC);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `GetMonitorInfo()` to determine the size and *position* of the window. [How do I switch a window between normal and fullscreen?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100412-00/?p=14353)

Comment: @zett42 thanks, but i'm already aware of that. i'm only looking for the answer to this particular problem that i've simplified down for simplicity.

Comment: just found a small solution `SetWindowRgn(hWnd,CreateRectRgn(0,1,w,h+1),false);` that'll stop it from intruding outside the desktop. still a dirty hack, but it's all i have for now.

Answer (score 0):

When running your code, I don't actually get any transparency, so I can't understand why you are needing to overflow the screen. But here's how I changed your code to work for me, and without overflowing the screen.

```
// libs needed to compile: opengl32 gdi32 dwmapi

#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

HDC hDC;
HGLRC hRC;
HWND hWnd;

bool running = true;

int w = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), h = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

void CreateContext() {
  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd; hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
  SetPixelFormat(hDC, ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd), &pfd);
  hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC); wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
}

void EnableTransparency() {
  SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  const MARGINS margins = { -1 };
  DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (uMsg) {
  case WM_CLOSE: running = false; return 0;
  case WM_KEYDOWN: if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) { running = false; } return 0;
  }return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void CreateWin() {
  WNDCLASS wc = {};
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.lpszClassName = "OpenGL";
  RegisterClass(&wc);

  hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, wc.lpszClassName, "Title", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, wc.hInstance, 0);
  ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
  CreateContext();
  EnableTransparency();
}

void PumpMessages() { MSG msg; while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))DispatchMessage(&msg); }

int main() {
  CreateWin();
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h); // the visible screen area
  while (running) {
    PumpMessages();
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // fill solid black
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); // transparent triangular window
    glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 0.5f); glVertex3f(0, 1, 0); // red   (center)
    glColor4f(0, 1, 0, 0.5f); glVertex3f(-1, -1, 0); // green (left)
    glColor4f(0, 0, 1, 0.5f); glVertex3f(1, -1, 0); // blue  (right)
    glEnd();
    SwapBuffers(hDC);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Checking error codes has been left out. Essentially, we use a window with the layered style to get transparency. We call SetLayeredWindowAttributes with no flags, because we are not using any of these layered window features, but we need to call the function for the window to become visible.

Comment: when i run this nothing is rendering, but the window itself is still fullscreen and you can see the desktop beneath it. i tried my own code above again and now it's just a flickering transparent triangle on the desktop. i tried at actual screen size too and it's no longer taking away the desktop, but rendering is still messed up. this is pretty messed up. although other code i have will still steal the display when using exact resolution. you got a better example source?

Comment: update: i fixed my example above. i had to correct EnableTransparency() and also call it before CreateContext(). see if you get the problem with the updated source.

Comment: Your example works for me now, and I see no difference whether or not I add 1 to the height of the window. To be clear, I get a solid black window, with a colourful transparent triangle that I can see through. What exactly are you trying to achieve and what is the problem that you are having?

Comment: it's stealing the display so there's no desktop rendered beneath it. when you removed the +1 from the height, did you also remove the -1 from the y position? it's not just when it's the exact size. it has to cover the whole screen too. (for the taskbar to go away) also, the reason i moved the window up is cause the viewport is at the bottom (so you don't have to move the viewport down 1 pixel when in fullscreen. cause that'd be dodgy)

Comment: Yes I did that, and everything works fine. Not sure what is causing your problem then.

Comment: ok try doing this. just create a simple fullscreen window with opengl rendering on it. no transparency. see what happens. (hint. vsync will also be needed to stop the screen tearing)